# Save the worksheet and delete file button

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following question. I use a file to log assets (laptops, desktops etc) into certain folders, like deployed, stock, repair and hotswap.

I made some buttons in it which work all fine. One button called deployed, when I save the sheet with this button it saves it with EU IMAC, serial number and date as XLMS file.

I like to change the code from this button, so that when I save a sheet as deployed it automatically delete the XLMS file with serial number and name in the folder stock.

Below the codes for all the save buttons and it's button 61 that needs to be fixed, the others I will change afterwards. The code is form other forum, but with no success.

```
Sub Button60_Click()
    Range("A1:G68").PrintOut
End Sub

Sub Button51_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\rjbakkex\Documents\Assets_logging\Hotswap\" & Format(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EU IMAC").Range("B26").Value) & " - Hotswap -" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
End Sub

Sub Button53_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\rjbakkex\Documents\Assets_logging\Returned to stock\" & Format(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EU IMAC").Range("B26").Value) & " - Return to stock - " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
End Sub

Sub awaitwuhan_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\rjbakkex\Documents\Assets_logging\To repair\" & Format(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EU IMAC").Range("B26").Value) & "- Repair -" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
End Sub

Sub Button61_Click()
    p = "C:\Users\rjbakkex\Documents\Assets_logging\Deployed\"

    'opslaan
    s_name = Sheets("EU IMAC").Range("B25").Value & " - Deployed -" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs p & s_name

    'verwijderen
    d_name = Sheets("EU IMAC").Range("B25").Value & " - Return to stock -" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
    If MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to remove " & d_name & " from the system?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Sure?") = vbYes Then Kill p & d_name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, give your buttons meaningful names, that is such a garbled mess to try and determine what button60 is or does.

Second You need to use the file system object from Microsoft Scripting Library (add a reference in excel to this dll scrrun.dll) then you can check to see if the file exists and delete it

```
Sub Button61_Click()
    p = "C:\Users\rjbakkex\Documents\Assets_logging\Deployed\"
        'opslaan
        s_name = Sheets("EU IMAC").Range("B25").Value & " - Deployed -" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs p & s_name

    'verwijderen
        d_name = Sheets("EU IMAC").Range("B25").Value & " - Return to stock -" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
    'create the file system object
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    'make sure the file exists first
    If fso.FileExists(p & d_name) = True Then

        If MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to remove " & d_name & " from the system?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Sure?") = vbYes Then
            fso.DeleteFile p & d_name, True
        End If


    End If
    'free the memory
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```